# Lightroom: create smart collection for specific development setting value?

Tags: lightroom, software, black-and-white, smart-collections

How can I create a collection of photos which Saturation setting is set to 0 ?

Answer (score 1):

With the current version of Lightroom this is not possible, however you can create a smart collection of images based on their `Treatment` which can be either `color` or `black and white`:

[image: Create Smart Collection dialog]

If you can find a way to set your black and white photos to use this `Treatment` flag to indicate they are monochrome (again, I can see no quick way to do this), then you should be able to create and maintain a smart collection of this kind.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed this filter. Unfortunately this is not how I create my black and white photos. I just set the saturation to 0. Thanks